# Is there a way to check for new fields in the protobuf message?

Tags: protocol-buffers

What I want to do is to validate the data inside a protobuf message before I send it to an external network.  This is providing a security check.

The problem is that protobufs allow sending additional fields using an updated proto file, which allows backwards compatibility.

What this means is when I go to check a message, my autogenerated code parses the object, but drops the unknown fields. So this means the transmitted bytes could have information I don't know about.

A work around would be to transmit the version of data I have parsed and checked, which would mean dropping the new fields.  That's the right security thing to do, but I still won't know that someone is sending me new version of messages.  It would be nice to log that and be told I might need to update.  I also want to communicate back to the sender that some of their data is being dropped.

Is there a way to know if the format of the message I received mismatches from the format I expect to receive?

Comment: Many protobuf frameworks have an inbuilt mechanism for tracking unexpected fields. Which library/framework/language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java with maven
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
and
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>

Comment: So: getUnknownFields? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090867/how-to-deal-with-unknown-protobuf-fields-in-java